# Keep getting the following error "Please install the sqlite3 adapter: `gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter`"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, gemfile

Trying to run rails s and i get the error:
"Please install the sqlite3 adapter: `gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter`"

have tried bundle update and bundle install, seems to happen just after i push the app to heroku (did the same thing with another app and got the same error so started again)

Trying to create a controller but the error keeps appearing. Did what it said and tried the command "gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter" and get the following:
"Could not find a valid gem 'activerecord-sqlite3-adapter' (>= 0) in any repository"

and also added the gem to the gemfile , then ran 'bundle install' but made no difference

have tried creating the sqlite db again by running both of the following:

bundle exec rake db:create
rake db:mirgrate

neither makes any any difference.
using the following ruby version: ruby 1.9.3p125

using the following database.yml:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000


# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Gemfile is as follows:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

#sqlite for dev
group :development do
 gem 'sqlite3'
end

#PG for Heroku

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'devise'
gem "rails_best_practices"

#administration:
gem 'activeadmin'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

whole error looks like this:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:147:in `block in replace_gem'
te3-adapter` (sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.) (LoadError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `re
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `bl
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `lo
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `re
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:82:in `block (2 l
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:74:in `block in <
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_ini
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_mi
        from C:/Users/Scotty_W7/Dropbox/Rails Apps/imagemoose/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `re
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `bl
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `lo
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `re
        from C:/Users/Scotty_W7/Dropbox/Rails Apps/imagemoose/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
        from C:/Users/Scotty_W7/Dropbox/Rails Apps/imagemoose/config.ru:in `new'
        from C:/Users/Scotty_W7/Dropbox/Rails Apps/imagemoose/config.ru:in `<main>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (requir
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I would go for a Postgres database in Heroku. I think you can't use Sqlite3, but I'm not sure...

Answer (score 1):

You must need `sqlite adapter` to run your application.
To install the adapter just open command prompt and type

```
gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter
```

Wait for a while to install the adapter. After the installation try to run your app..

Comment: Hi
when i run that command i get the following error:
"Could not find a valid gem 'activerecord-sqlite3-adapter' (>= 0) in any repository"

Comment: did you have the SQLite3 gem installed??

Comment: just ended up scraping it all and creating a new app. solved the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you change your config/database.yml to use postgres instead of sqlite?